# Ubuntu booting problem ( Not booting)

Tags: boot, dell, crash, bootloader, reboot

[image: image after booting]

I am using a Dell laptop, Inspiron 15 series  (inspiron 15-3565) with Ubuntu 20.04

**Today I suddenly removed my laptop battery when it was in use. After that, whenever I tried pressing power button it's not booting into Ubuntu. I tried several times, waited more than 2 hours once, but every time it's getting stuck here.**

I looked for several solution on YouTube but nothing worked.

Is there any way to fix it without losing my files in the harddisk?  I don't want to lose them. Am using single boot.

```
Bios vertion: 1.8.0
Product name: Inspiration 15-3565
```

Comment: Can you boot into a live session from installation media?  If you don't want to lose important data, keep backups. By not keeping backups in a different location, you are all-but guaranteeing that you will eventually lose the data.

Comment: @Nmath My English is bad, didn't get what you asked. Is there any way to get my data?

Comment: "Try Ubuntu" with a flash drive containing Ubuntu. You may be able to access your system if you can't fix it.  See: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install

Comment: Try removing the CMOS battery for 5 minutes and putting it back in the reset to BIOS back to its defaults. Then insert a live Ubuntu USB and select it as the first priority in the BIOS boot sequence and comment if it boots successfully.

Comment: The post is 2 days old, maybe you fixed it. Just as info: interrupting linux can cause exactly what you see. Some files in the beginning of your disk are broken, these are the files the PC needs to start. You data should be mostly intact, but should can destroy them doing the wrong thing. For someone very new to Linux its not very easy to fix this. If you know someone who is a bit experiences with Linux its a good idea to ask him for help because quite a few steps are involved to get you safely back on track.

Comment: The live CD with of the tool BootRepair may be helpful